# ExecutionPolicy issue preventing access to Package Manager Console in VS

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, package-managers

I am attempting to access the Package Manager Console in my VS 2013 but I am getting the following:

> Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of Unrestricted. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".

I tried Google and did a couple of things then restarted my VS, but nothing: same issue!

Why is this happening and how can I fix it so that I can access the Package Manager Console? Right now when I run `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` I get the following:

```
Scope             ExecutionPolicy
-----             --------
MachinePolicy     Unrestricted
UserPolicy        Undefined
Process           RemoteSigned
CurrentUser       RemoteSigned
LocalMachine      RemoteSigned
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out I had some pending updates for NuGet Package Manager and PowerShell Addon for VS. Once I installed those and restarted my PC. All was good!

Answer (score 4):

I installed this hotfix (I use VS 2013 and Windows 8.1) and it fixed this exact problem for me (make sure to get the correct version for your IDE):

[NuGet downloads](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html)

Comment: Fixed the bug on VS 2013 for me. Thanks.

Comment: fixed for me in vs2013; note i just installed LATEST from https://dist.nuget.org/index.html - as of 11/1/2016 that's 2.12.0

Comment: That's what the link in the answer is, so it should always point to the latest.